Call to a member function links() on array error with custom pagination in laravel 10
I'm trying to create a custom pagination in laravel 10, but I'm getting the error code

Call to a member function links() on array

this is my code:
CulinaryController.php
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $client = new Client();

        $qs = http_build_query($request->query());
        $qs = $qs ? '?'.$qs : '';
        $url = initURLPath("culinary" . $qs);
        $response = $client->get($url);
        // dd($response->getBody()->getContents());

        $json = json_decode((string)$response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        
        if ($request->query('dd')) {
            // dd($response->getBody());
            dd($json);
        }

        $view_data = [
            'title' => 'Browse Culinary',
            'data' => $json,
        ];
        return view('culinary.index', $view_data);
    }

Api/V1/CulinaryController.php
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $perPage = $request->query('per_page', 8);
        $currentPage = $request->query('page', 1);
        $pageOffset = ($currentPage - 1) * $perPage;

        $result = Culinary::get();

        $data = $result->toArray();

        $resultWithPagination = new LengthAwarePaginator(
            array_slice($data, $pageOffset, $perPage),
            count($data),
            $perPage,
            LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage(),
            [
                'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
                'query' => $request->query(),
            ]
        );

        return $resultWithPagination;
    }

and this is the code that causes the error in the blade view:
{{ $data->links() }}

any help is appreciated.

If you are asking why your PHP object is not preserved when you get it via an HTTP request then the answer to that is because the response of your HTTP request is in JSON. If you want to preserve your object then you should move your pagination logic outside of the CulinaryController so you can call it from both CulinaryController and  Api/V1/CulinaryController or alternatevely the JSON response from CulinaryController should include the links but you'd need to know which array entry to look for them in

if I were to move the pagination logic outside of the Api/V1/CulinaryController.php file then wouldn't the actual CulinaryController.php receive a really big data when calling the index method in the API? I'm guessing I would need to apply some kind of "pagination" using limit and offset in the Culinary::get() part, no?

What I was suggesting was creating a function which returns an instance of a LengthAwarePaginator which you can use in both controllers. Api/V1/CulinaryController::index would just return the result of that function while CulinaryController::index could further process it if necessary. Out of curiosity, why do you not use Culinary::paginate ? It's meant to be more efficient when working with database collections

I tried using Culinary::paginate($perPage) too but I still get the same error message.. also, as you can see in my current code in the Api/V1/CulinaryController.php I'm already returning an instance of LengthAwarePaginator.. is there something else I can try?

Apologies. I don't think I was clear enough: If you use $response = $client->get($url); you will get a JSON array as the result. Not the LengthAwarePaginator. You will need to get the object directly instead of getting it over an HTTP request.

The error is telling you exactly what the problem is:

Call to a member function links() on array

So let’s look at where you call links:
{{ $data->links() }}

So you’re trying to call a links method on a variable named $data. So let’s see where that variable comes from:
$json = json_decode((string)$response->getBody()->getContents(), true);

// [Snipped]

$view_data = [
    'title' => 'Browse Culinary',
    'data' => $json,
];
return view('culinary.index', $view_data);

Oh. You set the value of data from $json, which is the result of json_decode-ing some HTTP response to be an associate array.
So yes, $data is an array. You cannot call class methods on arrays, because arrays are not classes.
Error messages seldom lie. If it’s telling you a variable is an array then it’s most likely an array, and not an object like you think it is. So if you step through your code instead of assuming, you will find you’ll eventually find the underlying problem.

is there a solution for this problem?

Try reading the error, and my explanation of the problem, above.

yes, fortunately I understand English quite well so I understand what the error message means. I also know that I can't use -> on an array variable, and when I dump the $data variable I see that links is not a function but an associative array. what I'm actually looking for is how to display the pagination links.

$data is an array. It’s not an object. Therefore you can’t call methods—like links()—on it. So stop treating it like an object. You can’t magically call pagination methods on something that isn’t a pagination instance.
